# Add more id's or classes to a Javascript script

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

How can I add multiple id's or classes to this Javascript script in order to change their CSS properties on the scroll value?

```
<script>
    var fixed = false;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if( $(this).scrollTop() >= 434 ) {
            if( !fixed ) {
                fixed = true;
                $('#sub-header').css({position:'fixed',top:82});
            }
        } else {
            if( fixed ) {
                fixed = false;
                $('#sub-header').css({position:'static'});
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** My explanation may not have been as clear as I thought. I'd like to include additional elements via their id or class to the script. For example, add an addition line for #header. I tried adding `$('#header').css({position:'fixed',top:0});` under the #sub-header lines but it didn't work. (I'm a complete newbie to Javascript so forgive me if this is elementary.)

Here's the basic html code:

```
<header id="header></header>
<div id="sub-header">
    <nav id="nav"></nav>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
<footer id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".class1, .class2, #id1, #id1").css("display", "block");
```

or

```
$(".class1").add(".class2").css("property", "value"); // etc
```

Comment: See EDIT above. Does this affect your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

```
$('.your class').addClass('newClass');
```

Comment: See EDIT above. Does this affect your answer?

Comment: can you also add the html relevant to the script please?

Comment: I added the basic html. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you create the class in a stylesheets, after you will can use toggleClass jQuery function.

```
<script>
    var fixed = false;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        if( $(this).scrollTop() >= 434 ) {
            if( !fixed ) {
                fixed = true;
                $('#sub-header').toggleClass("withTop noTop");
                //Or use addClass and removeClass
                $('#sub-header').addClass("withTop");
                $('#sub-header').removeClass("noTop");
            }
        } else {
            if( fixed ) {
                fixed = false;
                $('#sub-header').toggleClass("withTop noTop"); //This

                //Or this
                $('#sub-header').addClass("noTop"); 
                $('#sub-header').removeClass("withTop");
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
.withTop{
    position:static;
}
.noTop{
    postion:fixed;
    top:82;
}
</style>
```

Comment: See EDIT above. Does this affect your answer?